# While loops and breaking when boolean becomes false

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, breakpoints

I am trying to make a loop whereby the program keeps on going until bank>100000, and within that while loop there is another while loop which determines whether bank has reached a minimum(whether user has failed, and bank resets to 20000).
Currently the loop runs and continues forever even if successive iterations reach the 1000000 condition. Can anyone see a way of resolving this?

n.b. 'singles' is just an array containing one number.

Many thanks.

```
i = 0
newbank = []
iterations = []
while bank < 1000000:
    bank = 20000
    while bank > 100:
        spin = randint(0, 38)
        if choices2 == singles:
            if spin == singles:    
                bank = bank + (bet * 35)
            else:
                bank = bank - bet
            i = i + 1
            iterations.append(i)
            newbank.append(bank)
```

Comment: Fact: I find code with 1-space indents too hard to read.

Comment: what is the value of bet ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: enjoy :)

Comment: Offtopic: I can not imagine more awful pythonic code. D: "iterations.append(i)" - WHY?! Do choices2 change during this cycle? Do you really need this if statement?

Comment: The value of the bet is 100<=bet<=20000 in 100 increments.

Comment: @joe: if `singles` is an array, `spin`, an int, will never be equal to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `while` continues to run even if `bank < 10000000`, so you'll never leave that loop, and if you do, well, you'll stay on the first loop.

There is no way your code can stop.

Do you want something like...

```
while bank > 100 and bank < 1000000:
```

I don't know exactly what logic you're trying to achieve, but you need to think better about your stopping conditions.

Edit:

Upon reading your question better, I think you should get rid of the two loops, since one will be more than enough.

Initialize your `bank = 20000` outside the loop,

```
bank = 20000
while bank < 1000000:
    if bank < 100:
        bank = 20000

....
```

Comment: D'oh! Yeah had forgotten to set the limit of the bank in the second while loop  to <1000000